# AngularJS + JQuery = TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Trying to debug a JS issue, but not having any success - trace is below.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined    
    at Object.fn (angular.min.js:937)
    at l.$get.l.$digest (angular.min.js:508)
    at l.$get.l.$apply (angular.min.js:522)
    at HTMLLIElement.<anonymous> (angular.min.js:928)
    at HTMLLIElement.x.event.dispatch (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:10)
    at HTMLLIElement.x.event.add.v.handle (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:10)
```

Issue is that the code generating the error does not include 'then' - I'm removing objects from an array, the error throws when the last object is removed but the app continues to function correctly. Wondering if it's just an internal Angular error that I can ignore?

How can I better trace the cause?

Comment: Will you please provide some code?

Comment: as a first step, instead of a minified version of angular js use a dev version so that we will be able to find out which angular line is causing the error... also which is the angularjs version used

Comment: @ArunPJohny - switched out to dev version, which lead me to updating to a newer ngAnimate module. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Updated ngAnimate module, problem gone.